# Find all running processes with a certain name linux

Tags: linux, shell, process

I am new to linux, and I want to write to a .txt file all of the running processes on my PC that has the word "con" in them.

The script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -A | grep "con" > con_proc.txt
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Works fine on my computer, how do you run the script ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -eaf | grep -i "con" > con_proc.txt
```

If you want to place inside of a script the contents of the script would be the above contents, for example `script.sh`.

To invoke the script you will need to do the following:

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

The first command gives the script execute permissions and the second command invokes the script.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has [`pgrep`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) to do this.

```s
$ pgrep -a con
...
```